# jQuery button a href text

Tags: html, css

I have a href link as jquery button

```
$("a.button, button, input:submit", "div").button();

<a href="/Home/Acton" class="button">Back</a>
<button name="submit" id="continue" value="continue">Continue</button>
```

as a result i have that:

[image]

So the issue is that `Back` text in a href not white, in order to fix I've added the style below.

```
/*jQuery buttons a href style fix*/
a.button:link {color: #fff !important;} 
a.button:hover {color: #026890;}
```

I could see in firebug that style is applied but it is does not help, the `Back` text still not white.

The thing is that when `Back` is on hover it is looking good but when not on hover text should be white the same way like `Continue` has, but it is not.

How may i fix that in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set `a:visited` to be white thats why you have such situation and also you may set `a:hover` to be `#026890`

So try that:

```
/*jQuery buttons a href style fix*/
a.button:link {color: #fff !important;} 
a.button:visited {color: #fff !important;} 
a.button:active {color: #026890 !important;} 
a.button:hover {color: #026890 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it that the 'Back' link has been visited? If you set the css for the 'visited' version of the link does that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using this code:

```
a.button {color: #fff}
a.button:hover {color: #026890;}
```